# How can I prevent Clickjacking attack on my Prestashop website?

Tags: security, prestashop-1.6, x-frame-options, clickjacking, client-side-attacks

I added the

```
<meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="deny">
```

in **header.tpl** file ,but it not working and throws an error.

> X-Frame-Options may only be set via an HTTP header sent along with a document. It may not be set inside .

And I also added the

```
Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
```

line in **.htaccess** file. But this is also not working.

***Then how can I prevent Clickjacking on my Website?***

For references :  [Clickjacking Defense Cheat Sheet | OWASP](https://owasp.org/www-project-cheat-sheets/cheatsheets/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet.html)  and [X-Frame-Options - HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options)

Comment: Why do you think the response header is not working? Does the server send it? That's the right solution.

Comment: Okay. But in cPanel how can I add the header in httpd.conf ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to edit the .htaccess in your PrestaShop root folder installation and, just before the lines identified by "# ~~start~~ Do not remove..." add the following block:

```
# Extra Security Headers
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
   Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'self' *.googleapis.com *.gstatic.com;"
   Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
   Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
   Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
   Header set Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload
</IfModule>
```

This will provide protection against:
clickjacking - content sniffing - XSS attacks